# Apache Ignite backed with my SQL failing to start in client mode when embedded with Spring Boot- Showing configuration mismatch

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ignite

I started apache ignite server 2.6.0(binary distribution) with a custom configuration and a spring boot application with the similar configuration in client mode. When tried starting the spring boot application, the spring boot application is showing the error message as configuration merge. Below is the message from console

```
Caused by: org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiException: Conflicts during configuration merge for cache 'PersonCache' :
PERSON conflict:
keyFieldName is different: local=id, received=null
```

Can you let me know how to resolve this. This is working as expected when I use Spring boot embedded ignite server and Spring boot embedded client with a similar configuration

Ignite XML Configuration

```
<bean id="datasource"
    class="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource">
    <property name="URL"
        value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/ignite" />
    <property name="user" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="*****" />
</bean>
<bean id="gridCfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
    <property name="cacheConfiguration">
        <list>
            <bean
                class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
                <property name="name" value="PersonCache" />
                <property name="readThrough" value="true" />
                <property name="writeThrough" value="true" />
                <property name="writeBehindEnabled" value="true" />
                <property name="cacheStoreFactory">
                    <bean
                        class="org.apache.ignite.cache.store.jdbc.CacheJdbcPojoStoreFactory">
                        <property name="dataSourceBean" value="datasource" />
                        <property name="dialect">
                            <bean
                                class="org.apache.ignite.cache.store.jdbc.dialect.MySQLDialect">
                            </bean>
                        </property>
                        <property name="types">
                            <list>
                                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.store.jdbc.JdbcType">
                                    <property name="cacheName" value="PersonCache" />
                                    <property name="keyType" value="java.lang.Long" />
                                    <property name="valueType"
                                        value="pl.piomin.services.ignite.model.Person" />
                                    <property name="databaseSchema" value="ignite" />
                                    <property name="databaseTable" value="PERSON" />
                                    <property name="keyFields">
                                        <list>
                                            <bean
                                                class="org.apache.ignite.cache.store.jdbc.JdbcTypeField">
                                                <constructor-arg>
                                                    <util:constant
                                                        static-field="java.sql.Types.INTEGER" />
                                                </constructor-arg>
                                                <constructor-arg value="id" />
                                                <constructor-arg value="java.lang.Long" />
                                                <constructor-arg value="id" />
                                            </bean>
                                        </list>
                                    </property>
                                    <property name="valueFields">
                                        <list>
                                            <bean
                                                class="org.apache.ignite.cache.store.jdbc.JdbcTypeField">
                                                <constructor-arg>
                                                    <util:constant
                                                        static-field="java.sql.Types.VARCHAR" />
                                                </constructor-arg>
                                                <constructor-arg value="first_name" />
                                                <constructor-arg value="java.lang.String" />
                                                <constructor-arg value="firstName" />
                                            </bean>
                                            <bean
                                                class="org.apache.ignite.cache.store.jdbc.JdbcTypeField">
                                                <constructor-arg>
                                                    <util:constant
                                                        static-field="java.sql.Types.VARCHAR" />
                                                </constructor-arg>
                                                <constructor-arg value="last_name" />
                                                <constructor-arg value="java.lang.String" />
                                                <constructor-arg value="lastName" />
                                            </bean>
                                            <bean
                                                class="org.apache.ignite.cache.store.jdbc.JdbcTypeField">
                                                <constructor-arg>
                                                    <util:constant
                                                        static-field="java.sql.Types.VARCHAR" />
                                                </constructor-arg>
                                                <constructor-arg value="gender" />
                                                <constructor-arg value="java.lang.String" />
                                                <constructor-arg value="gender" />
                                            </bean>
                                            <bean
                                                class="org.apache.ignite.cache.store.jdbc.JdbcTypeField">
                                                <constructor-arg>
                                                    <util:constant
                                                        static-field="java.sql.Types.VARCHAR" />
                                                </constructor-arg>
                                                <constructor-arg value="country" />
                                                <constructor-arg value="java.lang.String" />
                                                <constructor-arg value="country" />
                                            </bean>
                                            <bean
                                                class="org.apache.ignite.cache.store.jdbc.JdbcTypeField">
                                                <constructor-arg>
                                                    <util:constant
                                                        static-field="java.sql.Types.VARCHAR" />
                                                </constructor-arg>
                                                <constructor-arg value="city" />
                                                <constructor-arg value="java.lang.String" />
                                                <constructor-arg value="city" />
                                            </bean>
                                            <bean
                                                class="org.apache.ignite.cache.store.jdbc.JdbcTypeField">
                                                <constructor-arg>
                                                    <util:constant
                                                        static-field="java.sql.Types.VARCHAR" />
                                                </constructor-arg>
                                                <constructor-arg value="address" />
                                                <constructor-arg value="java.lang.String" />
                                                <constructor-arg value="address" />
                                            </bean>
                                            <bean
                                                class="org.apache.ignite.cache.store.jdbc.JdbcTypeField">
                                                <constructor-arg>
                                                    <util:constant
                                                        static-field="java.sql.Types.DATE" />
                                                </constructor-arg>
                                                <constructor-arg value="birth_date" />
                                                <constructor-arg value="java.util.Date" />
                                                <constructor-arg value="birthDate" />
                                            </bean>
                                        </list>
                                    </property>
                                </bean>
                            </list>
                        </property>
                    </bean>
                </property>
                <property name="queryEntities">
                    <list>
                        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.QueryEntity">
                            <property name="keyType" value="java.lang.Long" />
                            <property name="valueType"
                                value="pl.piomin.services.ignite.model.Person" />
                            <property name="keyFieldName" value="id" />
                            <property name="keyFields">
                                <list>
                                    <value>id</value>
                                </list>
                            </property>
                            <property name="fields">
                                <map>
                                    <entry key="id" value="java.lang.Integer" />
                                    <entry key="firstName" value="java.lang.String" />
                                    <entry key="lastName" value="java.lang.String" />
                                    <entry key="gender" value="java.lang.String" />
                                    <entry key="country" value="java.lang.String" />
                                    <entry key="city" value="java.lang.String" />
                                    <entry key="address" value="java.lang.String" />
                                    <entry key="birthDate" value="java.util.Date" />
                                </map>
                            </property>
                            <property name="indexes">
                                <list>
                                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.QueryIndex">
                                        <constructor-arg value="id"/>
                                    </bean>
                                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.QueryIndex">
                                        <constructor-arg value="firstName"/>
                                    </bean>
                                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.QueryIndex">
                                        <constructor-arg value="lastName"/>
                                    </bean>
                                </list>
                            </property>
                        </bean>
                    </list>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="peerClassLoadingEnabled" value="true"></property>
</bean>
```

Comment: It's hard to say what is going on exactly. I tried your configuration, it works just fine. Without a reproducer it would be hard to help you.

Comment: It looks like your client and server actually use different configurations. Perhaps the client has some Java code changing the configuration or something. In any case, you need to share more details.

Comment: I figured this out. Actually I am facing this exact same problem right and I was running my project with persistence mode true after storing the cache what I did is change the root package name in my java code So before it was `com.cgs.springboot` After changing it became `com.cgs.platform` therefore I am getting the error as `Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiException: Conflicts during configuration merge for cache 'UserCacheConfig' : 
USER conflict: 
valType is different: local=com.cgs.springboot.dto.User, received=com.cgs.platform.dto.User`...can anyone tell how to delete